# Plesk migration

Tags: migration, plesk

Is it possible to migrate plesk from  a 32bit server to a 64bit server?

I am getting the error while migrating

> Warning: The uploaded backup file (cus11_cust11.com_info_1507301442.xml.tar) was modified, corrupted, created on another server or in an older Plesk version that does not support signing of backups. Before restoring data from this backup file, make sure you can trust the source of this file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
Regarding mentioned warning you can read this KB article - http://kb.odin.com/en/125354
I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Plesk Migrator for migrating from one server to another. It connects via SSH to your old server and it copies all data and settings to the new server. [More information...](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/migration-guide/migrating-from-supported-hosting-platfoms/migrating-via-the-plesk-interface.75721/)